# Spring Data JPA BigList insert

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, bulkinsert

I've been trying for two days now to store an array list with about six million entries in my Postgres database with Spring-Data-JPA. 
The whole thing works, but it's very slow. I need about 27 minutes for everything. 
I've already played around with the batch size, but that didn't bring much success. I also noticed that saving takes longer and longer the bigger the table gets. Is there a way to speed it up ? 
I've done the whole thing with SQLite before, there I only needed about 15 seconds for the same amount.

My Entity

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "commodity_prices")
public class CommodityPrice {

    @Id
    @Column( name = "id" )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE )
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "station_id")
    private int station_id;

    @Column(name = "commodity_id")
    private int commodity_id;

    @Column(name = "supply")
    private long supply;

    @Column(name = "buy_price")
    private int buy_price;

    @Column(name = "sell_price")
    private int sell_price;

    @Column(name = "demand")
    private long demand;

    @Column(name = "collected_at")
    private long collected_at;


    public CommodityPrice( int station_id, int commodity_id, long supply, int buy_price, int sell_price, long demand,
            long collected_at ) {
        this.station_id = station_id;
        this.commodity_id = commodity_id;
        this.supply = supply;
        this.buy_price = buy_price;
        this.sell_price = sell_price;
        this.demand = demand;
        this.collected_at = collected_at;
    }
}
```

My insert Class

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CommodityPriceHandler {

    @Autowired
    CommodityPriceRepository commodityPriceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void inserIntoDB() {

        int lineCount = 0;
        List<CommodityPrice> commodityPrices = new ArrayList<>(  );
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();


        try {
            Reader reader = new FileReader( DOWNLOAD_SAVE_PATH + FILE_NAME_COMMODITY_PRICES );
            Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse( reader );
            for( CSVRecord record : records ) {
                int station_id = Integer.parseInt( record.get( "station_id" ) );
                int commodity_id = Integer.parseInt( record.get( "commodity_id" ) );
                long supply = Long.parseLong( record.get( "supply" ) );
                int buy_price = Integer.parseInt( record.get( "buy_price" ) );
                int sell_price = Integer.parseInt( record.get( "sell_price" ) );
                long demand = Long.parseLong( record.get( "demand" ) );
                long collected_at = Long.parseLong( record.get( "collected_at" ) );

                CommodityPrice commodityPrice = new CommodityPrice(station_id, commodity_id, supply, buy_price, sell_price, demand, collected_at);
                commodityPrices.add( commodityPrice );

                if (commodityPrices.size() == 1000){
                    commodityPriceRepository.saveAll( commodityPrices );
                    commodityPriceRepository.flush();
                    entityManager.clear();
                    commodityPrices.clear();
                    System.out.println(lineCount);
                }

                lineCount ++;
            }
        }
        catch( IOException e ) {
            log.error( e.getLocalizedMessage() );
        }

        commodityPriceRepository.saveAll( commodityPrices );


        stopWatch.stop();

        log.info( "Successfully inserted " + lineCount + " lines in " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds() + " seconds." );
    }
}
```

My application.properties

```
# HIBERNATE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

Comment: You don't need commodityPrices.size() == 1000 if you are already setting spring batch size in your application.properties. When you call saveAll(), spring batch would automatically persist based on batch.

Answer (score 0):

While you are doing your insert in batch, your sequence generation strategy still requires you to issue one statement for each record you insert. Thus, for a batch size of 1000 records you issue 1001 statements, which is clearly not what is expected.

**My recommendations:**

- enable sql logging to see what statements are sent to your db. I personally use [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy), but use anything you are happy with.
- modify your sequence generator. At a minimum, use

```
@Id
@Column( name = "id" )
@GeneratedValue(generator = "com_pr_generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE )
@SequenceGenerator(name="com_pr_generator", sequenceName = "book_seq", allocationSize=50)
private long id;
```

- Read about different generation strateges and fine tune your sequence generator.

  - [A beginner’s guide to Hibernate enhanced identifier generators](https://vladmihalcea.com/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/)
  - [Hibernate pooled and pooled-lo identifier generators](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/)